# @Scripts.Render() <script> tag links to a Html source code page, and scripts are not detected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is where i include the ScriptBundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.js", "~/Scripts/popper.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js", "~/Scripts/Index.js"));
```

When i debbug the application the script tags are rendered separately, and it works well. The problem is when i publish the project, the scripts are rendered in a single tag; i know that AspNet compress all the scripts in a single tag, but the web page does not detect the scripts and when i click on the link of the rendered  tag, it directs me to a source code page (HTML) in which the scripts should be.

This is the  tag:

```
<script src="/scripts?v=r8NL2JoYrRk4WG4L8aUu1037yymdncGQgFxOAcbEyw41"></script>
```

And this is the link: [script_tag_link](http://jobstock20171025114709.azurewebsites.net/scripts/?v=r8NL2JoYrRk4WG4L8aUu1037yymdncGQgFxOAcbEyw41)

Here is how the page of the link looks:
[Here should be the compressed scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29QqO.png)

Answer (score 1):

The ScriptBundle name, in this case "~/scripts", shouldn't match an existing folder in your application. Try changing it to "~/bundles".